# How many different adjacency matrix does a graph with N vertices and E edges have?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, adjacency-matrix

The answer is N! and I don't understand how it is.

My view:

Assuming it is an undirected graph;

The dimension of each row in a adj. matrix of a vertex is N irrespective of the number of edges. Hence, the number of permutation possible for first row= N!.

Total permutation for second row= (N-1)! since one cell has already been taken care in the first row. 
Similarly, third row= (N-2)!
.
.
.
For Nth row=1

Total permutation= N! + N-1!+...+1!

I am confused if considering an undirected or directed graph will yield different result or not. How will the answer change if we consider graph to be directed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll take a shot at it, but please ask questions if it's unclear. For it to be N!, we are assuming an undirected graph.

For a graph with N vertices, it would be represented with an NxN matrix (2D array) with each value being either 0 (edge does not exist) or 1 (edge exists). In this, we are not considering other weights on edges.

Then, we consider all of the possible assignments. If there are N different choices on the first row, there must be N-1 choices on the second row (since we already know about the edge 1,2) and so on.

N * (N-1) * (N-2) * ... * 1 = N!

Comment: Thanks! I think you're correct. I don't know why I was considering the arrangement of those possible choices available for each row. Any idea how we'll find the answer for directed graphs?

Comment: For directed graphs, you gain no information about any of the rows by looking at previous rows, so I would say it should be N*...*N = N^N

Comment: @Brian What's the role of E(number of edges)? For example, if we've 2 edges in a graph having N vertices then we can have (nC2)*(n-1C2) number of matrices, since we need to add one edge by choosing any two vertices and 2nd edge must be added between another pair of vertices where one of them should not be from the vertices chosen in step1.

Comment: Shouldnt **maximum possible number of adjacency matrices for n node graph** be (n!)^2 for both undirected and directed graphs? We can permute rows of adjacency matrix in n! ways. Similarly we can permute columns of adjacency matrix in n!. For both directed and undirected graphs, permuting any one or both of rows and columns will give new adjacency matrix. So shouldnt it be (n!)^2?

Comment: I would say that, since an adjacency matrix is symmetric, but can contain loops, you can create a binary string by concatenation of the rows of the upper triangle of the matrix (including the diagonal). The amount of ways you can fill such string of p=n(n+1)/2 elements with 0s and 1s is 2^p. If you instead want m edges exactly, then you have m 1s and p-m 0s, so you want to know the number of ways you can permute a string of p elements taking into account repetitions, which if I'm not wrong is p!/(m!(p-m)!)

Comment: That is exactly the binomial coefficient (p m). You can consider that 2^p is the sum of all matrices with 0 edges + all with 1 edge + all with 2 edges... or sum(m=0 to p) of (p m), which is exactly 2^p so my logic looks like ok.